# How to add icon for particular icon in column header in jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

How to add icon for particular icon in column header in jqgrid? I have tried to add  it in colmodel it works but after clicking on that icon it sorts the grid as well.So without touching the sorting how to add icon for particular column in column header

```
colNames:['Id','Location','Address <span class="infoIconForGaps"</span>&nbsp'],
```

Comment: How is the icon defined in colModel? Can you please post a example?

Comment: Edited the question. It gives the icon but when I click on that icon it does the sorting as well. I don't want to do sorting on click of that icon need to give popup message.Otherwise it should do sorting if I do not click on that icon

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the following trick using the parameter disableClick

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function stopsort() {
        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam',{"disableClick":true});
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
            colNames:['Id','Location','Address <span class="infoIconForGaps"  onclick="stopsort()"></span>&nbsp'],
        ....
```